# Proper JSDoc annotations in WebStorm for functions with variable number of arguments?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jshint, jsdoc

I've read through a bunch of answers to this question, and tried some different variants of them myself as well, but so far I haven't managed to find anything that satisfied WebStorm. The code in question looks something like this:

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

/**
 * @param {function} func The original function.
 * @param {...*} args Bound argument values.
 * @returns {function} The partially applied function
 */
function partial(func /* args */) {
    var args = slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return function() {
        return func.apply(this, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
    };
}
```

The above code triggers a warning saying "Parameter args described in JSDoc does not appear in function signature". Internally in WebStorm, they have some JS files similarly annotated to support auto-completion for things like Function.prototype.call, but those are used only as libraries. As such, they can have whatever in their signature, so they just add an extra argument at the end for this (would be "args" in this case). In regular code, that's not really an option, though.

Is there any form of this syntax that WebStorm actually accepts without complaints, or is this just a bug/missing feature?

Comment: note that Google Closure compiler (http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) doesn't accept this JSDoc as well: JSC_INEXISTANT_PARAM: parameter args does not appear in partial's parameter list at line 7 character 0
function partial(func) {
So this doesn't look to be a bug in WebStorm

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly from Michael Bollin's book, you still need to add the second param to the function signature, even though you will access the extra arguments through JavaScript's special array-like arguments object (available to every function), not the one you specify in the signature.

Comment: Unfortunately, then you have JSHint complaining about a defined but unused variable. I guess you can add a comment to suppress that warning, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: I see... Looks like adding a suppress warning comment might be the cleanest/less ugly way to do it.